# Delete on cascade for two foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem, I have a table that contains two foreign keys from an unique column like this:

[image]

**Note:** id_maquina_camino is "unique" and both of tables are needed as are shown.

If I add the foreign keys everything go fine, but when I try to add delete on cascade I have an error:

```
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__camino__destino__300424B4' on table 'camino' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

The code:

```
ALTER TEST.dbo.camino
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (origen) 
    REFERENCES maquina (id_maquina_camino)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TEST.dbo.camino
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (origen) 
    REFERENCES maquina (id_maquina_camino)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TEST.dbo.camino
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (destino) 
    REFERENCES maquina (id_maquina_camino)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TEST.dbo.camino
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (destino) 
    REFERENCES maquina (id_maquina_camino)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: That error message suggests that you can't cascade on delete twice between the same two tables.  You would need a trigger instead.

Comment: I considered that option too, seems that is the solution. Thanks @jmcilhinney.

Comment: Never, never name variables and sql objects in a language other than English. It's a shame

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot (easily) mimic `on update cascade` using a trigger and a plain foreign key (with no cascade actions) - also, you'd normally specify all cascade actions (for both update and delete) in a single `FOREIGN KEY` constraint - at the moment, you're attempting to create 4 foreign keys.

Comment: @nZeus why do you think that all objects and variables need to be in English? That doesn't make any sense at all. Why would the front end support multiple languages if what you say is true?

Comment: @SeanLange Have you ever worked in the international team? Have you ever continued the development of the existing project written in another language? Have you ever tried to understand the code written in German/Spanish/Russian? No? I had to.

Comment: @nZeus glad you can make assumptions about what I have or have not done. How do you know that English is the native tongue of the company where this is written? Yes I would prefer English but that is my native tongue. That doesn't mean that I would demand that everything be written in a language that makes it easy for me.

Comment: WOw, I think that is not the matter to discuss here but well @nZeus do not worry about me, all my team are Spanish people and is more easy for us communicate in our native language. When I work with an international team, I write everything in English so don't worry :)